# Need to symbolicate a crash report for react native expo app using eas for build

Tags: ios, eas, symbolicatecrash

I’m currently facing a production error with my react native expo build using eas. Generated a build using eas for iOS , when I tried to open on real device , the app crashed with this.

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwatL.jpg)

Got the crash logs for the issue. Now symbolicating the crash log for a expo managed work flow   ,I need to  obtain  the source map and .dysm files . I tried to use sentry-expo but it’s getting complicated .

So I integrated Bugsnag into my React Native Expo project by following the comprehensive documentation available https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/. Despite diligently following all the necessary steps to set up Bugsnag for error tracking, I encountered an issue. After generating a new build and testing it on a real device, I noticed that the error logs were not appearing on the Bugsnag dashboard.

Upon investigation, I observed that only the source map was successfully created under 'Project > Uploaded mapping files' on the Bugsnag dashboard. Despite this, the actual error logs seemed to be missing. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights on how to ensure the seamless capture and display of error logs for effective debugging and monitoring through Bugsnag."

Or is there any better approach to symbolicate the crash report. Please shed some light on this issue, Thank you.